# Hide #VALUE! until the entry is inputed

Tags: microsoft-excel

In "Column A" I plan to input First & Last name. In "Column B" & "Column C" I have the following formulas to trim and spilt the name into their respective columns. Question - How do I hide the "#VALUE!" until an entry is made in "Column A"?

=LEFT(A2351,FIND(" ",A2351)-1)

=RIGHT(A2352,LEN(A2352)-FIND(" ",A2352))

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your formulas in an `IFERROR` that returns nothing in case of an error:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A2351,FIND(" ",A2351)-1),"")

=IFERROR(RIGHT(A2352,LEN(A2352)-FIND(" ",A2352)),"")
```